FastReport Last Page spacing of the GroupFooter
Good day all
I need help with the spacing of the group footing chaing on the last page. All the other pages it prints with a space which is perfectly fine but the last page doesn't print with that space which is a problem as it's not uniform. Please help?
Please see image, hopefully it makes more sense seeing it visually.
I've tried ticking Keep Child Together

The main difference between the last group footer and the rest is no group header follows it.

Please see what image?
